# PHP Include Always Fails

Tags: php, apache2, mod-fcgid, suexec

- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.21 with VirtualHosts under SuExec
- PHP 5.3.8 via fcgid
- Arch Linux 2011.08.19

I am in the process of migrating from shared hosting to VPS. The code I had ran fine before the move but is now failing at this line:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/content/header.php');
```

Error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening
>   required '/srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/header.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /srv/www/hostname/public/index.php on line 3

I tried the same line without the document root part, with and without `./`, etc. with no luck. No difference with `require`, `include_once`, or `include`, either. Yet, I can verify that the file exists at that exact location by copy-pasting from the error log and `cd`ing to it…

But just to be absolutely sure, I tested the return values of the `include`s as well as `file_exists`—they all return false. Yet all of the files are chown'd by the SuExec user/group, and no combination of permissions helps (on directories or files); have tried from 644 to 777. What's going on here?

**Edit**:

- Same result with files in the same directory.
- Apache & SuExec error logs reports nothing.
- Safe Mode is set to "Off" in `php.ini`.
- `dirname(__FILE__)` and `exec('pwd')` return the same as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but without the trailing slash.
- `fread`, `file_get_contents`, and `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` all return false.
- `set_include_path()` has no effect.
- Running `require` via `php-cgi` directly from the command line returns Internal Server Error while `include` returns blank output; running either via `php` returns blank output.

Here's my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/hostname/public/"
    ServerName hostname.com
    ServerAlias www.hostname.com
    SuexecUserGroup hostname hostname
    ErrorLog "/srv/www/hostname/logs/error.log"
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog "/srv/www/hostname/logs/access.log" combined

    <Directory /srv/www/hostname/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # http://www.linode.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2982
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php5_filter.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php5_hooks.c>
    <IfModule mod_actions.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        AddHandler php-fcgi .php
        Action php-fcgi /fcgid-bin/php-fcgid-wrapper
        Alias /fcgid-bin/ /srv/www/hostname/fcgid-bin/

        <Location /fcgid-bin/>
            SetHandler fcgid-script
            Options +ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>

        ReWriteEngine On
        ReWriteRule ^/fcgid-bin/[^/]*$ / [PT]
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: since he using php 5.3  feature has been DEPRECATED according to: http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Comment: I also made sure that safe mode was explicitly set to "Off" in `php.ini`.

Comment: Can you check what user runs: fcgid

Comment: I've found something that may help: http://www.webhostchat.co.uk/hosting-software-additional-add-products/20774-how-set-up-phpsuexec-vps.html

Comment: It's the SuExec user, same user that owns all of the files and directories in the docroot.

Comment: That link just says to turn Safe Mode off, which it is.

Comment: It's most likely improperly configured server or the permissions are off. You could also try calling a fread or file_get_contents and see what it returns. If it returns the same permissions error, then its 100% server issue.

Comment: I've already tried all possible permissions, as stated in the OP. `fread` and `file_get_contents` both return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back to post the [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/326085/48061):

I didn't realize that `open_basedir` was unaffected by Safe Mode being off—it was looking in `/srv/http/` but not `/srv/www/`, which would be the containing directory for `/srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check permission of folders containg that files ?

Folder should has read permission for apache (or any user that runs http-server).

Have you try add path to include path ?

```
$path = '/includes/content';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: Permissions on folder are fine. `set_include_path` has no effect.

Comment: There is problem with configuration not in your code. Can you check .htaccess file for AddHandler directive ?

Comment: I don't have a `.htaccess`. I've added my vhost config to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the file exists...

- Then try to navigate to it using
  www.hostname/public/includes/content/header.php (if your using
  something local it would be 
  localhost/public/includes/content/header.php)
- If that does not load either something is wrong with your
  installation or your file is corrupt.
- Try loading the header from somewhere else

Comment: included files don't need to be visible to browser as you refering.

Answer (score 0):

It always works to me ->

```
if ( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/' )
{
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
}
else
{
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
}
```

give a try!

**[EDITED]**

using dirname() function always works!  `$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';`  perhaps the problem is in your server. Not in the programming (script).

Comment: Already ruled out slashes/lack thereof; also, this is Linux, so the separator will always be slash. Please read the OP.

Answer (score 0):

[DerfK](https://serverfault.com/users/56830/derfk) over at ServerFault [nailed it](https://serverfault.com/questions/326028/php-include-always-fails/326085#326085): it was an `open_basedir` restriction.